# If else 'and' 'or'

Tags: c

Hello this is a piece my assignment code.

First "if" to test if all dice are equal, also they equal to round number of game.

Second "(else) if" to test if all dice equal, but they are not equal to round number.

Third "(else) if" to test if at least one dice is not equal to round number.

Fourth one is to test no dice equal to round number.

Note: printf just to test statements

But now program gives four. How can I fix it and also write this code better way?

```
int dice1=1, dice2=1, dice3=1, round=3, point=0;

    if(   (dice1 == dice2) && (dice2 == dice3) && (dice1 == dice3) && (dice1 == round) )    printf("1");        
    else if(   (dice1 == dice2) && (dice2 == dice3) && (dice1 == dice3) && (dice1 == round) )   printf("2");    
    else if( dice1==round ? point++ : point  || dice2==round ? point++ : point  ||   dice3==round ? point++ : point ) printf("3");  
    else printf("4");
```

Comment: Your first two conditions are identical. Also, why are you trying to execute increments inside of a conditional?

Comment: sorry it should be dice!=round

Comment: I appreciate that you're new to programming but you should try to look at this before you ask any questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're expecting the second condition, all dice equal but not equal to round, to trigger. But you're still checking:

```
dice1 == round
```

I.e. It's exactly the same as the first if check. Also, rather than checking 1 == 2, 2 == 3, 1 == 3 you could just check:

```
1 == 2 && 2 == 3
```

Because that means 1 must also equal if 3 if both conditions evaluate to true.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(dice1 == dice2 && dice2 == dice3) {
    if(dice1 == round)
        printf("1");
    else
        printf("2");
}
else if(dice1 != round || dice2 != round || dice3 != round)
    print("3");
else fi(dice1 != round && dice2 != round && dice3 != round)
    print("4");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((dice1 == dice2) && (dice2 == dice3) && (dice1 == round)) {
    printf("1");
} else if ((dice1 == dice2) && (dice2 == dice3) && (dice1 != round)) {
    printf("2");
} else if ((dice1 != round) || (dice2 != round) || (dice3 != round)) {
    printf("3");
} else if ((dice1 != round) && (dice2 != round) && (dice3 != round)) {
    printf("4");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your third if statement is checking the value of point
you have initialized point to 0
you are using point++ (post-increment), which means that the value of point will increase from 0 to 1 AFTER the if check.  You could fix it by using ++point instead of point++.
That would be a pre-increment, and the value checked by the if would be 1 instead of 0